# In NHibernate, using a Disjunction gives double results

Tags: c#, nhibernate, join, restriction, detachedcriteria

I'm trying to make a select with DetachedCriteria, I want to add several conditions seperated by OR at runtime.

If I use:

```
Restrictions.Or( cond1, Restrictions.Or(cond2, Restrictions.Or(cond3, cond4)) )
```

I get the result I want.

But if I use a Disjunction like so:

```
var disjunction = Restrictions.Disjunction();
disjunction.Add(cond1);
disjunction.Add(cond2);
disjunction.Add(cond3);
disjunction.Add(cond4);
```

And I have entities that cond1 and cond2 are true for them, at the results I get them twice (the same exact entity is returned twice in the list result).

I do not wish to use QueryOver because I'm trying to accomplish something that is hard to do with QueryOver (the end result of what I'm trying to do is to get an sql query from a json of filters).

What's causing the disjunction to return doubles? Is there a way to add a DISTINCT at the end? Am I doing it wrong and I shouldn't use disjunction for different conditions on the same table?

**UPDATE:**

For the DISTINCT part:

```
criteria.SetResultTransformer(new NHibernate.Transform.DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer());
```

or

```
Projections.Distinct(Projections.Id())
```

The real solution is as stated by *Radim Köhler* - The correct use of a sub query.

Comment: What is the actual SQL being returned? Are you also joining across several tables as this might be the cause of a cartesian product

Comment: I'm joining 2 tables and the 4 conditions are on the joined table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little excuse: the question does not provide any mapping, there is also missing the query... So one can only guess what's the problem. But let's try to provide some explanation

#### Why recieving not distinct?

Let's have two tables (as given in one of the comments below the question)

Parent:

```
ParentId | Name
1        | Parent_A
2        | Parent_B
```

Child:

```
ChildId | Color | ParentId
1       | green | 1
2       | grey  | 1
3       | gold  | 1
4       | green | 2
```

Having this if we will create the simple selection in a pure SQL

```
SELECT p.ParentId, p.Name
FROM Parent AS p
  INNER JOIN Child AS c
    ON p.ParentId = c.ParentId
WHERE 
  c.Color = 'green' OR c.Color = 'grey' OR c.Color = 'gold'
```

what will be the result of this query?

```
1 | Parent_A
1 | Parent_A
1 | Parent_A
2 | Parent_B
```

If we will convert it into similar criteria:

```
var sesion = ... // get session 

var parent = sesion.CreateCriteria<Parent>();

var children = parent.CreateCriteria("Children");

// restrict the children
children.Add(Restrictions.Disjunction()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Color", "green"))
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Color", "grey"))
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Color", "gold"))
    );

var list = parent
    .SetMaxResults(10) // does not matter in our example, but ... it should be used always
    .List<Parent>();
```

And this is the Criteria C# code, which will result in a multiple Parents *(because of the fact, that the same SQL will be generated as stated above)*

As we can see, the problem is definitely **not** on the NHiberante side. Really! NHibernate is not only innocent, but also doing what was required.

#### Solution

The solution is in the subselect

In the SQL it will be like this

```
SELECT p.ParentId, p.Name
FROM Parent AS p
WHERE p.ParentId IN (
  SELECT c.ParentId
  FROM Child AS c
    WHERE c.ParentId = p.ParentId
    AND c.Color = 'green' OR c.Color = 'grey' OR c.Color = 'gold'
)
```

That will provide us with the result we most likely want:

```
1 | Parent_A
2 | Parent_B
```

And how to do that in NHibernate?

```
var sesion = ... // get session 

var parent = sesion.CreateCriteria<Parent>();

//var children = parent.CreateCriteria("Children");
var children = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(Child));

// restrict the children
children.Add(Restrictions.Disjunction()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Color", "green"))
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Color", "grey"))
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Color", "gold"))
    );

// ad SELECT into this sub-select
children.SetProjection( Projections.Property("ParentId"));

// filter the parent
parent
    .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("ParentId", children));


var list = parent
    .SetMaxResults(10) // does not matter in our example, but ... it should be used always
    .List<Parent>();
```

Now, we do have sub-select (`DetachedCriteria` and `Subqueries` NHibernate features) and no more DUPLICATES!

Comment: That's great and exactly what I wanted!

One small question - Is it possible to add each of the 3 restrictions added to the sub query as a detached query them selfs?

I want this process to be automated without knowing the depth of the query and the number or type of restrictions.

Comment: I am only afraid, that if you will add them separately, all will be evaluated with the **AND** operator. So, most likely, automation should be done on the sub-select building side... I would say