# nhibernate QueryOver select one table after join

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, queryover

So I am having issues selecting just the Parent entities as this will also return the Child entities.
Currently I have the following entities:

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual string KeyPart1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string KeyPart2 { get; set; }    
    public virtual string KeyPart3 { get; set; }
    public virtual string ParentProperty { get; set; }

    public virtual ISet<Child> Children { get; set; } = new HashSet<Child>();
}

public class Child
{
    public virtual string KeyPart1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string KeyPart2 { get; set; }    
    public virtual string KeyPart3 { get; set; }
    public virtual string KeyPart4 { get; set; }
    public virtual string ChildProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And the actual Query:

```
Parent parentAlias = null;
Child childAlias = null;
var query = Session.QueryOver(() => parentAlias)
    .Left.JoinAlias(x => x.Children, () => childAlias)
    .Where(whereClause);
```

This generates the a sql statement very similar to this:

```
SELECT
    this_.KeyPart1 as KeyPart11_5_4_,
    this_.KeyPart2 as KeyPart22_5_4_,
    this_.KeyPart3 as KeyPart33_5_4_,
    this_.ParentProperty as ParentProperty4_5_4_,
    childalias1_.KeyPart1 as KeyPart11_6_6_,
    childalias1_.KeyPart2 as KeyPart22_6_6_,
    childalias1_.KeyPart3 as KeyPart33_6_6_,
    childalias1_.KeyPart4 as KeyPart44_6_6_,
    childalias1_.ChildProperty as ChildProperty5_6_6_,
FROM
    Parent this_ 
left outer join
    Child childalias1_ 
        on this_.KeyPart1=childalias1_.KeyPart1 
        and this_.KeyPart2=childalias1_.KeyPart2 
        and this_.KeyPart3=childalias1_.KeyPart3 
WHERE
    (SomeWhereClause)
```

Notice that this will return both Parent and Child tables. When

> query.List()

is run, it will retrieves all of the Parents + all of the children of each parent, creating duplicate parent entries in the end result list. I just want to retrieve all of the Parents or generate the a sql statement similar to the following:

```
SELECT
    this_.KeyPart1 as KeyPart11_5_4_,
    this_.KeyPart2 as KeyPart22_5_4_,
    this_.KeyPart3 as KeyPart33_5_4_,
    this_.ParentProperty as ParentProperty4_5_4_,
FROM
    Parent this_ 
left outer join
    Child childalias1_ 
        on this_.KeyPart1=childalias1_.KeyPart1 
        and this_.KeyPart2=childalias1_.KeyPart2 
        and this_.KeyPart3=childalias1_.KeyPart3 
WHERE
    (SomeWhereClause)
```

Does anyone have any tips on doing this using nhibernate's QueryOver API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be, to use **`Transformers.DistinctRootEntity`** For example:

```
var query = Session.QueryOver(() => parentAlias)
    .Left.JoinAlias(x => x.Children, () => childAlias)
    .Where(whereClause)

    // Here is the trick
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
```

See more in this Andrew Whitaker post:

#### [QueryOver Series - Part 4: Transforming](http://www.andrewwhitaker.com/blog/2014/06/19/queryover-series-part-4-transforming/)

The other way...

Well, I would not go, in fact I do go, do not use this approach. My really proved way is to:

1. Create query from Child and join parent (star schema)
2. If we have to query parent

   - for filtering through child use **subselects**
   - for loading children in batches use mapping setting **`batch-size`**

The first is obvious, and because we query star schema, we can easily use paging

The second would need some adjustments for filtering parent by child:

- [Fetching Paginated Entity with Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23485652)

For effective loading of child collection, we can profit from batch-size mapping. Check these:

- [How to Eager Load Associations without duplication in NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20970816)
- [How to implement batch fetching with Fluent NHibernate when working with Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20999028)

Comment: Thanks that worked however it sill seems to creates the same query then nhibernate filters out the data after the it is retrieved.